# How to display a property from a class in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

In my class `Student` I have a property `studentName` which I want to be displayed on each line of my ListBox.

My `ListBox` is bound to a `List<Students> studentList`

How do I display the name of each student in the list onto the ListBox ?

e.g

```
foreach(Student s in studentList){
    ListBox.DisplayOnNewLine(s.studentName);
}
```

Comment: Override the `ToString` method  of the `Student` class to return the name of the student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could make use of data binding as follows:

```
ListBox.DisplayMember = "studentName";
ListBox.DataSource = studentList;
```

Answer (score 2):

A Listbox uses the `ToString` function of the class it has to display to present an element. If you override the function, you can define yourself what you want the Listbox to display. In your `Students` class, you then can override the function for something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return studentName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite ToString in your class Student:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.studentName;
}
```

Comment: This is a violation of Seperation of Concern. You are misusing `ToString`.

Comment: @Aphelion No, it's not. Not necessarily. If (and I assume it in this case) the primary string representation of a Student object would be the students name it's absolutely suitable to overwrite ToString like I showed. In other words it's of the Students objects concern to represent itself. The ListBox uses ToString as a way to determine it's visible content as a fallback, which is leavereged in this case. No violation at all.

Comment: I was to fast in my judgement indeed. It could be a ToString should also contain studentId in example. But, it if is indeed simply a name, he can surely implicitly use it for the binding.

Answer (score 2):

set DisplayMember to property you want to display
e.g.

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "studentName";
```

this way you do not have to override ToString()